Optimizing a concurrent laravel function for creating a products order
I've been using laravel for a while now, but till now I have not worked in a concurrent enviornment, maybe a few times. Right now I am developing a function which is going to execute a payment. On this stage it is kind of a draft, where I am thinking of different situations that might occur and how they should be handled.
Inside the function the product quantity plays a crucial role, so I am using the DB:: and "lockForUpdate()" mechanism for the product record. I am curious about your opinion on that and do you think it is a sufficient solution concerning the data concurrency. If you have any improvement hints or just any comment concerning it, I would be very grateful if you share them with me. Thank you in advance!
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        // Begin transaction at the start of the function
        DB::beginTransaction();
    
        try {
            // Validation rules
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id',
                'items' => 'required|array',
                'items.*.product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
                'items.*.quantity' => 'required|integer|min:1',
                'shipping_address_id' => 'nullable|exists:addresses,id',
                'billing_address_id' => 'nullable|exists:addresses,id',
                'street_address' => [
                    'required_without:shipping_address_id',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                        if (!$request->filled('shipping_address_id')) {
                            $fail($attribute.' is required when shipping_address_id is not provided.');
                        }
                    },
                ],
                'city' => [
                    'required_without:shipping_address_id',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                        if (!$request->filled('shipping_address_id')) {
                            $fail($attribute.' is required when shipping_address_id is not provided.');
                        }
                    },
                ],
                'country' => [
                    'required_without:shipping_address_id',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                        if (!$request->filled('shipping_address_id')) {
                            $fail($attribute.' is required when shipping_address_id is not provided.');
                        }
                    },
                ],
                'name' => [
                    'required_without:shipping_address_id',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                        if (!$request->filled('shipping_address_id')) {
                            $fail($attribute.' is required when shipping_address_id is not provided.');
                        }
                    },
                ],
                'phone_number' => [
                    'required_without:shipping_address_id',
                    function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                        if (!$request->filled('shipping_address_id')) {
                            $fail($attribute.' is required when shipping_address_id is not provided.');
                        }
                    },
                ],
                'payment_method' => 'required|in:credit_card,cash_on_delivery',
                'stripeToken' => 'required_if:payment_method,credit_card',
            ]);
    
            // Additional validation for items based on payment_method
            $validator->after(function ($validator) use ($request) {
                foreach ($request->input('items') as $index => $item) {
                    
                    $product = $this->productRepository->findProductById($item['product_id']);
                    $product->lockForUpdate();
    
                    // Check if product exists
                    if (!$product) {
                        $validator->errors()->add("items.$index.product_id", "Product {$item['product_id']} not found.");
                        continue;
                    }
    
                    // Check if the product can be purchased with the selected payment method
                    if ($request->input('payment_method') === 'credit_card' && !$product->is_payWithCard) {
                        $validator->errors()->add("items.$index.product_id", "Product {$item['product_id']} cannot be paid with a credit card.");
                    } elseif ($request->input('payment_method') === 'cash_on_delivery' && !$product->is_cashOnDelivery) {
                        $validator->errors()->add("items.$index.product_id", "Product {$item['product_id']} cannot be paid with cash on delivery.");
                    }
    
                    // Check product quantity and purchase_out_of_stock
                    if (!$product->purchase_out_of_stock && $product->quantity === 0) {
                        $validator->errors()->add("items.$index.product_id", "Product {$item['product_id']} is out of stock and cannot be purchased.");
                    } elseif ($item['quantity'] > $product->quantity) {
                        $validator->errors()->add("items.$index.product_id", "Not enough quantity available for product {$item['product_id']}.");
                    }
                }
            });
    
            // If validation fails, return errors
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                DB::rollBack(); // Rollback if validation fails
                return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 400);
            }
    
            // Calculate total amount and total savings
            list($totalAmount, $totalSavings, $errors) = $this->calculateTotalAmount($request->items);
    
            // If there are errors in calculating total amount, return errors
            if (!empty($errors)) {
                DB::rollBack(); // Rollback if calculation errors occur
                return response()->json(['errors' => $errors], 400);
            }
    
            // Handle payment based on payment method
            if ($request->payment_method === 'credit_card') {
                Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
                $charge = Stripe::createCharge([
                    'amount' => $totalAmount * 100,
                    'currency' => 'lv',
                    'source' => $request->stripeToken,
                    'description' => 'Order for user ID: ' . $request->user_id,
                ]);
                $transactionId = $charge->id;
                $paymentStatus = 'Paid';
            } else {
                $transactionId = null;
                $paymentStatus = 'COD';
            }
    
            // Create shipping and billing addresses if not provided
            $shippingAddressId = $request->shipping_address_id ?? $this->createAddress($request, 'shipping');
            $billingAddressId = $request->billing_address_id ?? $this->createAddress($request, 'billing');
    
            // Create the order
            $order = Order::create([
                'user_id' => $request->user_id,
                'phone_number' => $request->phone_number,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'order_number' => $this->generateAlphanumericUuid(),
                'total_amount' => $totalAmount,
                'status' => 'pending',
                'billing_address_id' => $billingAddressId,
                'shipping_address_id' => $shippingAddressId,
                'total_savings' => $totalSavings,
            ]);
    
            // Create order items and update product quantities
            foreach ($request->items as $item) {
                $product = Product::find($item['product_id']);
    
                // Validate quantity again to prevent overselling
                if ($item['quantity'] > $product->quantity) {
                    DB::rollBack(); // Rollback if quantity validation fails
                    return response()->json(['error' => "Not enough quantity available for product {$item['product_id']}."], 400);
                }
    
                // Reduce product quantity
                $product->quantity -= $item['quantity'];
                $product->save();
    
                // Create order item
                OrderItem::create([
                    'order_id' => $order->id,
                    'product_id' => $item['product_id'],
                    'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
                    'price' => $product->price,
                    'total' => $product->price * $item['quantity'],
                    'is_onsale' => $product->is_onsale,
                    'sale_price' => $product->sale_price,
                    'total_savings' => $item['quantity'] * ($product->price - ($product->is_onsale ? $product->sale_price : $product->price)),
                ]);
            }
    
            // Create payment record
            Payment::create([
                'order_id' => $order->id,
                'amount' => $totalAmount,
                'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
                'transaction_id' => $transactionId,
                'status' => $paymentStatus,
                'total_savings' => $totalSavings,
            ]);
    
            // Commit transaction after everything is successfully created
            DB::commit();
    
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Order created successfully.']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Roll back transaction on error
            DB::rollBack();
    
            // Refund charge if payment was processed
            if (isset($charge)) {
                $charge->refund();
            }
    
            // Return error response
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Order creation failed: ' . $e->getMessage()], 500);
        }
    }


why is your validation inside the transaction?

To be completely honest, my logic was that I have to put it at the beginning because inside the custom validation rule I use $produch->lockForUpdate(). Thinking more of it, I came to a conclusion that I am not modifying it there, so it shouldn’t be used there, right? As I said I am still figuring out the flow.
